# Are AI's referred to with いる or ある?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, culture

For example, would a chatbot be referred to with いる or ある? If I wanted to ask "You have Siri, right?", would I say "Siriがいるだろう" or "Siriがあるだろう".

And what about for the Terminator? Or what about a robot like C3P0 or R2D2 (from Star Wars)? Or is there no precise rule, and it's all up to the feelings of the speaker (whether they consider them a thing/object, or something sentient/intelligent)?

Comment: Basically this depends on how humanlike you think each AI is, so there is no definite answer, and one single person may use both depending on the context. (Ask yourself, is Siri your friend, or your tool?)